# Pandas Create multiindex pivot table with year month and day from single time column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a single column with time (time since epoch if it matters) from an sql query.

```
time     value
1000000  10
1000001  15
1000002  20
...
```

I want to create a multiindex pivot table in Pandas automatically like so based on those values.

```
                  Value
2018    Jan       10
        Feb       15
        March     20
2019    Jan       25
        Feb       30
        March     35
```

Is there an easy way to do this automatically for a variety of incoming time columns? And in some cases if the user specifies I would like to add day as the third multiindex level

Comment: Please post some sample input data that maps to the expected output shown here.

Comment: Please share a sample of input data

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just so you know, the reason you're getting downvotes is because there isn't sufficient information for us to fully understand your question. Check out these guides on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and especially how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for good tips on designing a well crafted question that will be most likely to get good answers. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

If the column is a pandas.DateTime column, you can use the [`.dt` datetime accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors) to access attributes such as `df[col].dt.year`, `df[col].dt.month`, etc. You could assign these to new columns, then use pivot or set the index as you describe.